# How to Enable audio track change in <video> tag for DASH content?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, chromium, mpeg-dash

I have embedded DASH videos in webpage using `<video>` tag. This content has multiple audio tracks. I want to support audio track change.
I used `audioTracks[i].enable` feature to select a audio track. But the audio track is not changing.

```
if (selected == i) {
    audioTracks[i].enable = TRUE;
}
```

1. Is this the right way ?
2. Is there any other way for changing the audio track of DASH(.mpd) content?

By audio track change, i mean to initiate a track change event that can propogate to lower level. not to implement a track change itself.

I further tried,
audioLanguage and lang attributes of video tag as
 `document.getElementById(id).lang = selectedIndex;`
and
`document.getElementById(id).audioLanguage = selectedIndex;`
Even this doesnt seem to work.

To be more clear, as mentioned in answer by @Svenskunganka `audioTracks[i].enable=TRUE;` is not supported in chromium in version that is used.
So, Is there any alternate way of doing what `audioTracks[i].enable=TRUE` does.
I dont want to implement track change functionality. Requirement here is to just indicate a track change to the browser.

`EDIT`:
As we can see in https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_audiotracks.asp. This property is not supported in chrome. so what is the alternate way of indicating that track has to be changed?
Is there any other way ?. Or audioTrack is the only way (as i understand from search so far)?

Comment: What do you mean by "audio track change"? Have you provided names for the tracks during encoding?

Comment: @guest271314 I am trying to play http://dash.akamaized.net/dash264/TestCases/10a/1/iis_forest_short_poem_multi_lang_480p_single_adapt_aaclc_sidx.mpd . This content has multiple audio lang support. So for changing the audio lang here i am using audioTracks[i].enable

Comment: You can parse the `application/dash+xml` `document`, see post

Comment: It is not clear what requirement is?

Comment: To put the question in another way, Requirement is alternate of audioTracks[i].enable

Comment: Are you using `MediaSource` to stream media?

Comment: No. I am using <video> tag only. I dont know about MediaSource.

Comment: Then how is video playback rendered if the `src` is set to an `.mpd` file?

Comment: dash playback is supported in the environment that i use. So playback is not a issue. Track change for audio is not happening as  audioTracks[].enabled property is not working as expected in chrome.

Comment: What is the environment are you using? Have you attached event listeners to `AudioTrack` object, if that is requirement?

Comment: This issue is not specific to dash. As i understand it applies to all video contents with multiple audio tracks. The issue is with audioTrack support. as we can see in https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_audiotracks.asp. This property is not supported in chrome. so what is the alternate way of indicating that track has to be changed?

Comment: `.audioTracks` is supported in chrome, chromium. What version of chrome or chromium did you try to access `.audioTracks` property? What environment are you using to playback `application/dash+xml` files?

Comment: To play dash content is not direct. Linux we can use gstreamer media pipeline and make it play. audioTrack is not supported fully. You can refer https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/Yk8u329AmIs/xe3nxFNCAgAJ . It doesnt work for more than 1 track as i understand.

Comment: How is `gstreamer` related to browser environment and `DOM`? The `.audioTracks` are iterable at chromium 59

Comment: @guest271314 1. For media playback the browser can use the platform media support to play content.So we can setup gstreamer to be used for media playback. Its about how browser plays video by making use of platform support. 2. Yes .audioTracks is iterable in chromium but its feature audioTrack[i].enable is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You can request the `.mpd` file using `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()`, read the `application/dash+xml` response as text using `.text()` or `.responseText`, pass the text to `DOMParser()` instance `.parseFromString()` to create a `#document`, iterate `AdaptationSet` child nodes of `document.documentElement` `Period` element, use `.querySelector()` to get `Representation` child node then get `BaseURL` child node of `Representation`, where the URLs are `.textContent` having path to, at least at the file referenced, a file at the same directory.

We can also select the video URL, use `Promise.all()` to load and play both video and audio tracks for ability to call `HTMLMediaElement.captureStream()`, which we `.clone()` and pass to `resolve()` of `Promise` constructor, at chained `.then()` call `.addTrack()` on a `MediaStream()` instance for each track, then set `<video>` `.srcObject` to the `MediaStream` containing both audio and video tracks.

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");

const mediaStream = new MediaStream();

const url = "https://dash.akamaized.net/dash264/TestCases/10a/1/"

const mpd = "iis_forest_short_poem_multi_lang_480p_single_adapt_aaclc_sidx.mpd";

const avc = [];

video.oncanplay = video.play;

fetch(`${url}${mpd}`)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const xml = parser.parseFromString(text, "application/xml");
  const period = xml.documentElement;
  const tracks = period.querySelectorAll("AdaptationSet");
  for (let track of tracks) {
    const representation = track.querySelector("Representation");
    const {textContent:currentTrack} = representation.querySelector("BaseURL");
    console.log(currentTrack);
    // filter for specific track here, for example
    // where "english" is included within `.textContent` of node
    if (/english/i.test(currentTrack) || /avc/.test(currentTrack)) {
      avc.push(`${url}${currentTrack}`);
    }        
  }
  Promise.all(avc.map(media => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let v = document.createElement("video");
      v.src = media;
      v.volume = 0.5;
      v.muted = true;
      v.oncanplay = () => {
        v.play();
        resolve({
          currentMedia:v
        , stream:v.captureStream().clone().getTracks()[0]
        })
      }
    })
  }))
  .then(tracks_ => {
    for (let {stream, currentMedia} of tracks_) {
      mediaStream.addTrack(stream);
      currentMedia.muted = false;
    }
    video.srcObject = mediaStream;
  })
})
```

```html
<video controls></video>
```

Comment: Thanks. As i understand this explicitly sets a audio file link as the src of video tag. If it is like that then it is like implementing a track change. But i dont want to do it. I need to initiate a track change event. Which will be kind of generic for all DASH content. May be even for HLS. And this seems to set the audio file as src of video tag right ? if it is so is that fine ? since audio and video are 2 separate files in mpd.

Comment: The approach captures the streams of the files listed in `.mpd` file, then adds the `MediaStreamTrack` of each stream to a single `MediaStream` which is set at a single `<video>` object. We could alternatively use the first media elements' stream to add the second stream to. Yes, audio can be played at `<video>` element. Have not read any documentations of a "track change event" of the `HTMLMediaElement`, though that does not mean the feature does not exist. The `.mpd` file only served to provide the path to the discrete audio and video files for the workaround. We implement our own stream.

Comment: Ok. Ya then this method will implement track change itself. But i need to generate/initiate a track change event only. Thanks anyway. One doubt i got here in this method, then there will be 2 video elements. 1 playing audio and another playing the video right?.

Comment: The video elements are created to capture the stream. We play the stream at a single video element. Though, yes, each media resource is actually playing at two `HTMLMediaElement`s rendered on screen at a single video element. The approach is a workaround, as `.mpd` file does not render playback when tried at chromium 59; the browser will prompt to download the file when trying to request the `.mpd` file at address field of browser.

Comment: Note the Question includes the text _"2. Is there any other way for changing the audio track of DASH(.mpd) content?"_

Comment: Yes. But i mean other ways to generate a track change event. Not to implement track change itself. Since my intention is just to generate the right events. Anyway thanks for such informative answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate a track change event" and "generate the right events"? Which specific events are you referring to? The `.mpd` file itself will not render playback at chromium 59. How do we possibly "generate" an event where no media is being rendered in the first instance?

Comment: The event for track change. On track chage, There will be calls that will be initiated to indicate that a track change has been initiated. The audioTracks[i].enable does generate these calls/events. But they are not right. They always call for default track.

Comment: _"The event for track change"_ Can you share links to the specifications for "track change" event relevant to `"application/dash+xml"` files being set as `.src` of an `HTMLMediaElement`? At which browsers is that functionality currently implemented?

Comment: Please check the answer by @Svenskunganka . AudioTrack is the feature which is not supported fully in chrome. So i need some alternate to AudioTrack.

Answer (score 1):

The Audio Track API is not fully implemented cross-browser yet. See [caniuse for **Audio Track**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audiotracks). Your issue is likely that you use either Chrome or Firefox to test this.

[Chrome has implemented it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=249427) but have not yet announced when it will land.
It is implemented in Firefox 33 but is not enabled by default and has to be toggled via user preference. There seems to also be some issues with Gecko not being able to perform multi-track playback, which is why this feature has been disabled for so long (Firefox is at version 57 at the time of writing).

Comment: Thanks. Ok i am using chromium. It doesnt support audio track yet. Is there any other way that i can use for supporting audio track change ? I mean without using audioTrack ?

Comment: @LearningC I am not entirely sure, but there is a product called BitMovin that seems to have [solved that issue specifically for MPEG-DASH](https://bitmovin.com/multi-language-multi-audio/). The problem is that [their player's JavaScript code](https://bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/bitmovin-player/stable/7/bitmovinplayer.js?ver=4.8) is heavily obfuscated so it's tricky to find out how they solved it without reversing the obfuscation.