# How to play multiple audio track video in HTML5 <video>?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an MKV file with multiple audio tracks, with a languages each. I want to add a button to changes the language. Can someone help me do it ?

```
HTML:

<video autoplay id="videoid" controls controlsList="nodownload" disablePictureInPicture poster="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/user/images/loading.jpg">
                            <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/images_or_videos/<?php echo $content->image_or_video; ?>" type="video/webm">
                        </video>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var aud = document.getElementById("videoid");
    aud.onplaying  = function() {
    alert(aud.audioTracks.length);   
}
});
```

Comment: Do you mean an `.mpd` file [How to Enable audio track change in <video> tag for DASH content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560072/how-to-enable-audio-track-change-in-video-tag-for-dash-content). If you mean parsing a Matroska file or EBML see [jswebm - 
A javascript implementation of the Webm Demuxer (matroska)](https://github.com/jscodec/jswebm); [ts-ebml - EBML encoder and decoder](https://github.com/legokichi/ts-ebml)

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");

// mute all
for (var i = 0; i < video.audioTracks.length; i += 1) {
  video.audioTracks[i].enabled = false;
}

// show languages and labels
for (var i = 0; i < video.audioTracks.length; i += 1) {
  console.log(video.audioTracks[i].language)
  console.log(video.audioTracks[i].label)
}

// enable one
video.audioTracks[2].enabled = true;
```

Comment: I am getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>". It's because I am not getting video.audioTracks. Can you suggest me why I am not getting the same. I also cross checked that my video i.e. mkv file have multiple audios built in it. Here is metadata of my mkv file https://www.get-metadata.com/result/4d213345-19dd-4506-a53e-a07946d86c53

Comment: I have edited my question with code. Please have a glance. Thank you.

Comment: audioTracks is not supported on all browser see https://caniuse.com/#feat=audiotracks for details , @PrashantHanamghar